# How to use work manager to resolve problem with exiting from region after app is killed by user?

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-workmanager

I have a problem with [altbeacon library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library). I am preparing a small library in which one module scanns beacons in background and foreground. I have found  sample app in one library on Github and I have tested their code (application class) and everything is ok. After user goes to the task switcher and swipes an app off the screen, scanning is being continued in background.

But I am creating a library so I can't paste my code inside Application class. Insted of this I need to do something like this: MyLibrary.init(this) inside onCreate method in ApplicationClass. So I wrote a BeaconService class with exactly the same code like in application class. I have passed to this class application context (I checked that I have inside my BeaconService application context by debugging my code). After that when app is not killed by swapping off from task switcher evrything works perfectly. After killing the app I got exit from region event and I am not able to continue scanning even if the beacon is about 20 cm far from device.

I created an issue on altbeacon Github (you can find my sample code and logs [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/861)) and I got an answer that library is not design for my requirements. Moreover if I have further questions how to resolve my problem I should ask about that on stackoverflow.

So I have an idea that maybe I can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) and re-schedule scanning beacon worker (OneTimeWork) again and again.  This may be a way around the delay limits of scheduling background tasking which is introduced from Android 8+.

Belowe sample code:

```
class BeaconWorker(appCtx: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(appCtx, workerParameters) {

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineDispatcher
    get() = Dispatchers.Default

override suspend fun doWork() = supervisorScope {
    // rescheduling worker
    if(isActive) {
        enqueNextWork()
    }
    // make scan (This could be only one scan with list of found beacons)
    val beacons = makeScan()
    Result.success()
  }
}
```

How to achieve this using altbeacon library?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this too hard.

The Android Beacon Library is designed to scan for beacons in the background and auto restart itself after the app is killed to scan for beacons.  It does this all automatically out of the box with no need for you to create any wrapping services or work managers. Such wrappers are likely to make things more complicated and cause unexpected side-effects.

The above also works if you are making your own library that wraps the Android Beacon Library, provided that the library's AndroidManifest.xml entries are merged into your library's AndroidManifest.xml.  This will expose a number of internal Android Beacon Library services in the manifest, including StartupBroadcastReceiver, BeaconService, and ScanJob.  Those three services are needed to accomplish the functions in the first paragraph.

If you have done the above, the only other thing you need to do is to provide some code hook to set up your beacon monitoring/ranging at application startup.  This can simply be a POJO method call inside your library like `new MyLibraryManager().start(Context context);`  (You will likely have to pass a Context object as this is needed to create the Android Beacon Library's BeaconManager.)

For automatic scanning restart after the app is killed, the above hook must somehow be executed when the application starts back up. (The library auto restarts is services described above, but you still need to make calls to tell the library whether to start scanning and with what settings.)

The easiest solution is to instruct the developers using your library to put the call to the hook desribed above (e.g. `new MyLibraryManager().start(Context context);`) inside their own custom `Application#onCreate()` method.  You might be able to figure out some other clever solution with a BroadcastReceiver that does not require this.

Comment: I know that I can wrap your Library into my one but I need more control over beacons scanning. Restarting after the app is killed could be handled by WorkManager automatically. I need something like I showed in the code snippet. All I need to know is how to create a method that makes one scan and returns a list of nearby beacons. So the solution (maybe a method) that I need should setup BeaconManager and make one scan using your Library. The result should be a list of beacons, that’s all. So could you please tell me where (inside your Library) I can find a methods which are used for scanning?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer to this:: "All I need to know is how to create a method that makes one scan and returns a list of nearby beacons" is that the library is just not designed to let you do that.  Such functionality is inside an internal library class called CycledLeScanner.java, but that class is designed to start and stop scanning indefinitely on a cycle, and send results as Intents using more internal library classes.  You might have better luck starting and topping scanning yourself and just using the library's BeaconParser class to parse the scan results into Beacon objects.